# How to get past the "total_rows" when parsing JSON from CouchDB

Tags: jquery, couchdb

I'm using the following jQuery code to get a JSON file from CouchDB.

```
Function getURL() {
   var api_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5984/couchcontentqueue/_design/DocCollections/_view/view_all_by_url_name?key="favorite-flickr-photos"&?callback=?';

   $.getJSON(api_url, function(json) {
      var type = json.type;
      var desc = json.description;
      $("#dropBox h3").html(type);
      $("#dropBox p").html(desc);
   });
};
```

When I do a GET on that URL it provides back the following:

```
{
    "total_rows":6,
    "offset":5,
    "rows":[
        {"id":"f5ba37e5af406ab079d596f7a1f30a2d","key":....}
    ]
}
```

Firebug gives me the following error:
invalid label
http://127.0.0.1:5984/couchcontentqueue/_design/DocCollections/_view/view_all_by_url_name?key=%22favorite-flickr-photos%22&?callback=jsonp1304111285023
Line 1

I can't figure out how to get past that first line to get to the actual JSON object. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Can you post a bit more of the JSON and state which specific properties you'd like to access?

Comment: This particular JSON file has pointers to other documents. I'd like to be able to access the key as well as all items in the doc. {"total_rows":6,"offset":5,"rows":[
{"id":"f5ba37e5af406ab079d596f7a1f30a2d","key":"favorite-flickr-photos","value":{"_id":"f5ba37e5af406ab079d596f7a1f30a2d","_rev":"2-e25334d60ab7d2c1753d8871a5abc33d","doc_type":"DocCollections","url_name":"favorite-flickr-photos","name":"Favorite Flickr Photos","content1":"f5ba37e5af406ab079d596f7a175ab4a","user":"tabdon","content5":"f5ba37e5af406ab079d596f7a157a953"}}
]}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ?callback=

It looks like you are trying to do a JSONP request, but:

> {"total_rows":6, ...

Is a plain JSON response and not a JSONP call. If you don't mean to do a cross-domain JSONP request, get rid of the `callback` parameter and have jQuery parse the response as normal JSON.

If you *do* need to do cross-domain JSONP requests, and you understand the security risks of that, make sure you're using an up-to-date CouchDB version and add the directive:

```
allow_jsonp = true
```

to the .ini file in the `[http]` section.

> invalid label

is what you get when you try to execute/`eval` a string containing a JSON object. It is a quirk of JS parsing that the `"x"` in `{"x": "foo"}` is taken as a JavaScript ‘label’ (used rarely for `continue` statements) in a statement block, rather than an object property name in an object literal expression.

jQuery will use script execution instead of JSON parsing when it thinks you are doing a JSONP request. Having the ‘callback=’ parameter in your URL magically makes it think that.

Comment: Thanks - you set me on the right track. Through playing around with local json files instead of pulling from the CouchDB server, I was able to figure out (theory, anyway) that the .getJSON doesn't know what to do with the first part of that JSON string. Once I got the CouchDB server to give me a JSON reply without the total_rows stuff I was able to parse it successfully. I'm not that sharp with JSON yet, so perhaps there's a way to get around the total_rows stuff if it's there.

Answer (score 0):

```
var key = json.rows[0].key;
var doctype = json.rows[0].value.doc_type;
```

so on and so forth...