# How to get couchdb design docs into a different url thats not local

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, couchdb, couchdb-nano

Couchdb spits out a url that is like this 
 `http://127.0.0.1:5984/roxanne/_design/request/_view/images`

This has my database and all my json. The problem is I want all the json to be parsed and sent to a different url called /getDocuments. I am using node, express, nano.
In my server.js I have this code.

```
app.get('/getDocuments', function(req, res){
  var roxanne = nano.use('roxanne');
  nano.db.get('roxanne', function(err, body) {
    if (!err) {
      console.log(body);
    }
    res.json(body);
  });
})
```

Which is not what I want it print out this:

```
{
  "db_name": "roxanne",
  "doc_count": 7,
  "doc_del_count": 2,
  "update_seq": 12,
  "purge_seq": 0,
  "compact_running": false,
  "disk_size": 204904,
  "data_size": 3369,
  "instance_start_time": "1375974435712463",
  "disk_format_version": 6,
  "committed_update_seq": 12
}
```

Which doesnt help, I want all of the json that the url prints out and parsed.
I also did a little experiment and it said unexpected token ILLEGAL.

```
'{"total_rows":6,"offset":0,"rows":[
```

I found this which is my problem, but not exactly sure what it means.
[How to get past the "total_rows" when parsing JSON from CouchDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837476/how-to-get-past-the-total-rows-when-parsing-json-from-couchdb)

So my question is:

How do I get that localhost url with all the json into /getDocument so that later in my project I can just get the json and each through it.

THANK YOU! If you have any questions please ask.

ps: My experiment was this:

```
    var json = '{"total_rows":6,"offset":0,"rows":[
{"id":"American_Airlines","key":"American_Airlines","value":{"_id":"American_Airlines","_rev":"1-d915fad8f624769d274794717b60311f","name":"American_Airlines","industry":"Flight","employee_count":"820,712,807","revenue":"$1,219,280,981","lead_source":"Linkedin","use_case":"exec manag","sales_cycle":"80","adm":"Adm goes here","se":"Se goes here","path":"assets/upload-images/2013/08/1375890760.png","fileTime":"1375890760"}},
{"id":"Dicks_Sporting_Goods","key":"Dicks_Sporting_Goods","value":{"_id":"Dicks_Sporting_Goods","_rev":"1-90cc5645b417ba0658aa7dcf5d576a51","name":"Dicks_Sporting_Goods","industry":"Store","employee_count":"3,098,089","revenue":"$2,918,798","lead_source":"website","use_case":"seo, stuff, moar stuff","sales_cycle":"20","adm":"Adm goes here","se":"Se goes here","path":"assets/upload-images/2013/08/1375890818.png","fileTime":"1375890818"}},
{"id":"FedEx","key":"FedEx","value":{"_id":"FedEx","_rev":"2-709a9dba4723b77fb6c40b3f0110ef97","name":"FedEx","industry":"industy here","employee_count":"100,000,000,000,000","revenue":"$10,000,000,000,000,000,000","lead_source":"twitter","use_case":"use case","sales_cycle":"90","adm":"adm goes here","se":"se goes here","path":"assets/upload-images/2013/08/1375888322.png","fileTime":"1375888322"}},
{"id":"Five_Guys","key":"Five_Guys","value":{"_id":"Five_Guys","_rev":"1-936c3f2da5e20031d618b005e5080181","name":"Five_Guys","industry":"Burger Joint","employee_count":"452,342,362","revenue":"$2,352,235,235,234","lead_source":"linkedin","use_case":"Data","sales_cycle":"20","adm":"Adm goes here","se":"Se goes here","path":"assets/upload-images/2013/08/1375892543.png","fileTime":"1375892543"}},
{"id":"hulu","key":"hulu","value":{"_id":"hulu","_rev":"1-d60340fde35feabbf78463c28684f3e3","name":"hulu","industry":"Internet","employee_count":"124,243,521,346","revenue":"$34,624,573,467,245,643","lead_source":"Facebook","use_case":"unkown","sales_cycle":"333","adm":"Kenneth","se":"MEMMEMEME","path":"assets/upload-images/2013/08/1375892898.jpg","fileTime":"1375892898"}},
{"id":"jiffy_lube","key":"jiffy_lube","value":{"_id":"jiffy_lube","_rev":"1-6c6b6fe2213c541b9c437aa8c47286fd","name":"jiffy_lube","industry":"industy here","employee_count":"12,124,124,124","revenue":"$23,897,629,871","lead_source":"scrubs","use_case":"something ","sales_cycle":"90","adm":"Adm goes here","se":"Se goes here","path":"assets/upload-images/2013/08/1375890322.jpg","fileTime":"1375890322"}}
]}';
    var obj = JSON.parse(json);
    res.json(obj)
```

Which outputted:

```
var json = '{"total_rows":6,"offset":0,"rows":[
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

PS: This worked, so the problem is the total_rows, but I still need to figure out how to get my localhost to a different url.

```
var json = '{"id":"American_Airlines","key":"American_Airlines","value":{"_id":"American_Airlines","_rev":"1-d915fad8f624769d274794717b60311f","name":"American_Airlines","industry":"Flight","employee_count":"820,712,807","revenue":"$1,219,280,981","lead_source":"Linkedin","use_case":"exec manag","sales_cycle":"80","adm":"Adm goes here","se":"Se goes here","path":"assets/upload-images/2013/08/1375890760.png","fileTime":"1375890760"}}';
  var obj = JSON.parse(json);
  res.json(obj)
```

This worked,but like I said Im trying to figure out the main problem still then I will focus on the total_rows problem. Sorry I asked multiple questions in one. I think that may be confusing people.

**EDIT/ANSWER**
[Retrieving all Documents from couchdb using Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109527/retrieving-all-documents-from-couchdb-using-node-js)

This post right here helped me out so much! It solved many problems that I encountered. For future people that ever need help.

`db.view` is what i was looking for! Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you have a `newline` character in your json string. Try a single line and see if it parses. About the main question, I'm sorry, I don't really understand what you are saying. What seems to be the problem and what should the expected output be?

Comment: @randunel I used jsonlint and it was valid json. I will try the one line though. ahh man Im sorry I was hoping I wasnt to confusing. I dont know how else to explain  it. Im just trying to get the JSON from that localhost url to a different url that is called /getDocuments

Comment: @randunel I used one line. and it worked. So just  like the link I linked up there. The total_rows seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are querying for the database stats, not for a database document.
When you want to retrieve a specific document, this is how you use the driver:

```
var roxanne = nano.use('roxanne');
roxanne.get('document_id', function(err, body) {
    console.log(err, body);
});
```

Note the `roxanne.get` instead of `nano.get`.

If you want to get all the documents,

```
var roxanne = nano.use('roxanne');
roxanne.bulk('_all_docs', {include_docs: true}, function(err, docs) {
    console.log(err, docs);
});
```

Comment: Oh I see! The only problem is its trying to go 'http://localhost:5984/roxanne/roxanne'     I only need the first roxanne not the second?

Comment: You must put the document id as the get parameter. See edited answer.

Comment: You are indeed right! Thank you! It is printing it out now! My question is can I get all of the documents and not just one? :/ Sorry im so hard to work with.

Comment: Yes, use `roxanne.bulk("_all_docs"` instead of `get`. If you want the whole document, use `roxanne.bulk("_all_docs", {include_docs: true}, function(err, docs) {`

Comment: forogt comma in answer. thank you! Also roxanne.fetch is good too.